# Adobe fonts not syncing in browser and CC app

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, creative-cloud

My fonts are not being activated in Adobe when I try and use them in illustrator. I have been using it with no problems untill today. I have tried the troubleshooting tips on the adobe website..

- Toggling adobe fonts on and off in the preferences of the CC app
- Signing out
- Making sure Im signed in to the right account on both CC app and
  browser
- Connecting to a different network using my mobile    data
- Restarting my computer

I have logged in to adobe fonts on my chrome browser and also logged in to CC app and went to the adobe fonts section. The CC app however doesn't show up the recent fonts I have activated.

These are the fonts in my browser

[image]

And here is the Adobe CC app

[image]

Comment: Sounds terrible. Tech support is not on topic here though, so I have to vote to close the question, sorry. You should ask Adobe. As a temporary solution I would try going back a version or two and see if it works in the 2021 or 2020 version.

Comment: Hi. Tech support is generally off topic here because a solution may depend on your computer system/settings. It could even be a bug. It would probably be best to contact Adobe directly instead.

Comment: Came back today and now it works :/ go figure I guess I had to wait a day and come back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try restarting your Router.

My partner was having exactly the same as Birdlady9604. She'd spent several hours in contact with Adobe Tech Support,but they couldn't find a resolution to the problem. I then stumbled across this blog & upon reading Birdlady9604's last comment written on Feb 24 @ 22:12, I thought to myself what could have changed overnight & why did it work next day? It is possible that Birdlady9604 switched off her router overnight? So, I switched off our router, then switched it back on & then a couple of minutes later her adobe fonts were syncing.

Hope this helps somebody out there.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/113565)

Answer (score 0):

If you have macOS Monterey make sure to go to your network settings and uncheck "Limit IP Address Tracking" I was having that problem for a few days and I realized that setting was on. It started working as soon as i turned it off.

Hope that works!

Answer (score 0):

Million thanks for the solution by Fnaffles, super smart thinking! I've also had the issue with Adobe Fonts not activating, nothing worked. Adobe support tried debugging for a few hours to no success. The next day I found your solution, restarted the router and Adobe Fonts started working. So thank you!!